# Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object; using global

Tags: php

I have the code in question:

```
function get_installed_languages()
{
    global $sql;

    $languages = Array();

    $sql->query("SELECT short_name FROM languages ORDER BY short_name");

    if($sql->getNumRows()==1)
    {
        $languages[0] = "default"; 
        return $languages;
    }
    else
    {
        for ($i=0; $i<$sql->getNumRows(); $i++)
        {
            $get = $sql->getRow($i);

            if(trim($get['short_name'])=='')
                $languages[$i]='default';
            else
                $languages[$i] = strtolower($get['short_name']);
        }

        return $languages;
    }
}
```

It always returns:

```
Fatal  error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object
```

The problematic line is:

```
(742): $sql->query("SELECT short_name FROM languages ORDER BY short_name");
```

Here is the [complete file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4ftVHajHv3NQVc2dXpjb2M2TDA/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: `$sql` is probably not initialized/created yet when you try using it. Have you tried `var_dump( $sql );` before the problematic line? Or `if(!is_object($sql)) var_dump( $sql, debug_backtrace());`

Comment: You need to re write for loop i. e. Remove first if else block use if condition within for loop and instead of fetch row function use fetch all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help. It turned out to be an invalid path in the DB.
I am really graceful for your efforts in trying to help me!

Otherwise, you can check the whole file (if still interested). A link to it has been posted at the end of my original comment.

Cheers!